# Can I say "faster, smarter, and together"?

Tags: adverbs

Do these three adverbs work as a list? I'm wondering if this combination is grammatical.

This is the sentence:

> Join this group of developers to collaborate on how to build apps faster, smarter, and together.

The third word here, "together," doesn't match the other two and doesn't seem to belong. But I'm not sure what to use instead, or how to make this combination work.

Comment: Yes. The three adverbs don't really match, and there's an element of the more ludicrous variety of zeugma.  You're right to add the middleweight padding (social distancing?)  of the dash before 'together', and right in choosing this word as the odd one out.

Comment: Join us, collaborate.............and together.   How many times do you need to say the same thing?  I'm unsure if the apps you create are faster and smarter, or your creation process is faster and smarter.  Can you clarify that?

Comment: Taking your example as is, you could drop *and together*: "Join this group of developers to collaborate on how to build apps faster and smarter." Your adverbs are modifying *build*.

Comment: @RichardKayser - If the collaboration is intended to create a process or learn about a process whereby in future apps can be built together, as compared to individuals building apps on their own, then it makes sense to keep "together". (But the current wording doesn't work, "together" doesn't match "faster" and "smarter".)

Comment: @nnnnnn Together is superfluous. The goal is faster and smarter (whatever that takes is implicit, especially in smarter) and the sentence already says collaborate. If faster and better means or requires together, so be it. Otherwise just do whatever is necessary to achieve faster and better.

Comment: You all are arguing this because it's a matter of stylistic expression. Instead of jawing, just vote to close as opinion-based.

Comment: Are you wanting them to join you to build apps or to develop methods on building apps?